# Is it possible to return a typename T class through a POCO Remoting NG restful endpoint?

Tags: c++, rest, poco-libraries

I just want to know if anybody knows how to return a typename T class through a restful endpoint created with POCO remoting ng. A simplified version of what I tried:

```
//@ remote
//@ path="/rest/endpoint/{resource}"
class Endpoint
{
public:
    //@ $resource={in=path}
    template<typename T>
    T get(std::string); // returns some kind of data based on the path variable
};
```

Then the implementation would be something like

```
template<typename T>
T Endpoint::get(std::string resource)
{
    // returns the data based on the path variable
}
```

After doing the code generation and compiling, the generated classes did not know how to handle the typename T. Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this? Or is there a POCO class I could use to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since the specialization has to agree with the base template on the return type, you can make it so by adding a "return type trait", a struct you can specialize and draw the true return type from:

```
template<class T>
struct item_return{ typedef T type; };

template<class T>
typename item_return<T>::type item();

template<>
struct item_return<float>{ typedef int type; };
template<>
int item<float>();
```